# Why does my Livedrive briefcase show as "Disconnected" after upgrading to Windows 10 1511?

Tags: networking, network-drive

As a LiveDrive user, upgrading to Windows 10 build 1511 from Windows 10 (or possibly a lower version) will result in your LiveDrive briefcase (L:) appearing as "Disconnected network drive" despite functioning normally. This is a registry issue and I will detail the fix below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the registry editor (WIN+R, type "regedit") and navigate to the following location:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order
```

Edit the details for the key "ProviderOrder" to place the string "CbFs3," at the beginning of it.

**BROKEN AFTER WINDOWS 10 1511 UPDATE:**

```
RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient
```

**FIXED STRING:**

```
CbFs3,RDPNP,LanmanWorkstation,webclient
```

Close all open File Explorer windows and re-open one. Navigate to "This PC" and you should see everything in order again.